# Configuring apache to deny traversing to seperate domains

Tags: apache

So, I have just found something I've missed about Apache ...

I have 3 sites:

```
/var/www/site1files (www.site1.com)
/var/www/site2files (www.site2.com)
/var/www/site3files (www.site3.com)
```

Each have an index.html ...

Now, when I go to each site, they work as expected ...

But, if I go to `www.site1.com/site2files/index.html`, strangely, it brings up that file (www.site2.com/index.html) ... Surely there's something really wrong I've done with my configuration ...

apache.conf (all default with):

```
<Directory /var/www/site1>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/site2>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/site3>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And each has a conf file in enabled-sites:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@site1.com
                ServerName site1.com
                ServerAlias www.site1.com
                DirectoryIndex index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
        <Directory /var/www/site1>
                Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted
                ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
                ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
                ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems I was confused about how to set up apache ...

I removed the site1,site2 and site3 `<Directory>` blocks from the apache.conf file, and just left the conf files in enabled sites ... Kinda makes sense now that I think about it ...

Remedial apache documentation reading for me ...